# Make connection string ADO.NET

Tags: c#, database, connection-string, oledb, sql-server-express

How can you make a connection string for an `OleDbConnection`? I have tried a lot of combinations and variants, but nothing works. I use a MS-SQL platform with C# to make the connection for SQL EXPRESS.

1. `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\Data\Northwind.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;`
2. `Data Source=(local);Provider=SQLOLEDB;Initial Catalog=FastCycle;Integrated Security=true`
3. `Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=TRUE;providerName=System.Data.OleDb`
4. `Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=Northwind.mdb`
5. `Provider=SQLEXPRESS;Data Source=Northwind.MDB`

Comment: Your question is very unclear as to what connection you need/want.  You may want to look here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: also a querystring is the ?value=1&value=2 at then end of a url, do u mean connection string?

Comment: Is it a SQL Server or SQL Express?  Do you have the right client libraries installed?  What error messages do you get?  Is the ADO.NET site running as a specific user that has permissions to the database?

Comment: @DStanley: it is a SQL Express

Comment: Are you trying to access a specific instance or attach a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@paddy suggested me this site [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/). It help me to find the correct string. It was:

```
Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```